# select sub sub sql query on 3 tables

Tags: mysql

**table1 - customer_data**

c_id (int)

name (varchar)

**table2 - account_data**

a_id (int)

c_id (int) -> use `customer_data`.`c_id`

plan_id (int)

**table3 - game_data**

g_id (int)

sort (int)

a_id (int)  -> use `account_data`.`a_id`

game_name (var)

I using sub-query to select the game_data from account_data.
like that:

```
SELECT `a_id`,`c_id`,`plan_id`,
(SELECT `game_name` FROM `game_data` WHERE `a_id` = a.`a_id` ORDER BY `sort` ASC LIMIT 1) as main_game
FROM `accoubt_data` AS a WHERE `a_id` > 0 ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

this sql is work for select `game_data` from `account_data`

But I can't using it to select `game_data` from `customer_data`

How can I do something?

```
customer_data
 +----------------------+
 | c_id      | name     |
 +----------------------+
 | 1001      | Joe      |
 | 1002      | John     |
 | 1003      | David    |
 +----------------------+

account_data
 +-------------------------------------+
 | a_id      | cid      |  plan_id     |
 +-------------------------------------+
 | 6015     | 1002     |   34          |
 | 6028     | 1003     |   1           |
 | 6088     | 1001     |   9           |
 +-------------------------------------+

game_data
 +--------------------------------------+
 | g_id     | game_name    |    a_id    |
 +--------------------------------------+
 | 8011     | GTA5         |    6015    |
 | 8023     | WWE2016      |    6028    |
 | 8088     | FIFA16       |    6088    |
 | 8095     | FIFA17       |    6088    |
 | 8086     | FIFA15       |    6088    |
 +--------------------------------------+
```

this is base select

I need get this data from customer_data.c_id

```
 +--------------------------------------+
 | c_id   | name     | frist_game       | 
 +--------------------------------------+
 | 1001   |  Joe     | FIFA15           |
 | 1002   |  John    | GTA5             |   
 | 1003   |  David   | WWE2016          |  
 +--------------------------------------+
```

c_id > a_id > g_id  ORDER BY sort ASC

Comment: you have taken a lot of effort to type out your tables. Wouldn't it have been easier to copy paste output from `show create table` ?

Comment: I had edited my topic content, thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with join:

```
SELECT c.`c_id`,c.name,
       (SELECT `game_name` FROM `game_data` 
        WHERE `a_id` = a.`a_id`
        ORDER BY `sort` ASC LIMIT 1) as first_game
FROM `accoubt_data` a
JOIN customer_data c ON(a.c_id = c.c_id)
WHERE a.`a_id` > 0 
ORDER BY a.`id` DESC
```

Comment: hi sagi, I need use the customer_data.c_id to get the game_data. I had edited my topic content. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT cd.c_id,cd.name, first_game 
FROM account_data ad 
inner join game_data gd ON ad.a_id = gd.a_id order by gd.g_id,ad.a_id as games 
inner join customer_data cd on games.c_id = cd.c_id order by cd.c_id
```

Hope this works.